# How to CSS Button with thicker edges (see the image)?

Tags: css, button, frontend

I need to make a button like that, when in **normal** state it is only a simple text, when **hovering** this shape appear with thicker edges, and thinner line in the center (center line 1px, thicker corner 3px).

That's where i'm stuck on: https://codepen.io/pietrociatta/pen/LYdbyyB

```
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
 background:
       linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top right/10px 2px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top right/2px 10px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom left/10px 2px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom left/2px 10px,
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top left/10px 2px,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top left/2px 10px,
        linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom right/10px 2px,
        linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom right/2px 10px,
  
  
    linear-gradient(to right,orange, orange) top/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(to left,orange, orange) bottom/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom,orange, orange) left/1px 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top,orange, orange) right/1px 100%;
    
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}



body {
  background:#222;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a [mre] of your work-in-progress code.

Comment: Post Edited, with the codepen link and the css code

Comment: Note that we have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar), as the answerers have used, to provide a [mre]; something that can be run without making answerers do it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you need to add all your CSS code for the border in hover state like .box:hover and in .box simply the font size and all, check out the result on hover.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.box:hover {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) top right/10px 2px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) top right/2px 10px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) bottom left/10px 2px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) bottom left/2px 10px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) top left/10px 2px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) top left/2px 10px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) bottom right/10px 2px, 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) bottom right/2px 10px, 
    linear-gradient(to right, orange, orange) top/100% 1px, 
    linear-gradient(to left, orange, orange) bottom/100% 1px, 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, orange) left/1px 100%, 
    linear-gradient(to top, orange, orange) right/1px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text here </div>
```

Comment: Yeah but it is not solving the "centered outline", if you check the picture the thinner border is in the middle of the thicker border... but in the codepen they are aligned